# is there a possible way to put the object Json outsite the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, object

is there a way to change this json

```
"forms": [
    {
        "_id": "Untitled Form",
        "title": "Untitled Form",
        "answer": [
            {
                "username": "jansenstan2410@gmail.com",
                "date": "2022-11-02",
                "formId": "6361c5aaf7a02c177ebebb27",
                "answers": {
                    "test": [
                        "New Option"
                    ],
                    "email": "john@nabatisnack.com",
                    "dropdown": "New Option",
                    "radio": "3",
                    "date": "2022-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "time": "17:25"
                }
            },
            {
                "username": "adam@wegodev.coms",
                "date": "2022-11-03",
                "formId": "6361c5aaf7a02c177ebebb27",
                "answers": {
                    "test": [
                        "New Option"
                    ],
                    "email": "123123.12312@e.com",
                    "dropdown": "3",
                    "radio": "3",
                    "date": "2022-11-16T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "time": "09:44"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i try to loop it using javascript but it dont return the same value as i expected and only increasing the value into the array.., i try some logic but it wont return the same value as i want also

```
const newData = forms.map((item) => {
        var mappedAns = item.answer.map((data) => {
          let data_fix = {};
          Object.keys(data.answers).forEach((key) => {
            data_fix[
              key
                .replace(/[{()}]/g, "")
                .replace(/ :/g, "")
                .replace(/ /g, "_")
                .toLowerCase()
            ] = data.answers[key];
          });
          return { ...data, data_fix };
        });
        return { ...item, answer: mappedAns };
      });
```

Comment: If you provide the requested results I'll show you how to do it with a query

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = forms.map((item) => {
  var mappedAns = item.answer.map((data) => {
    Object.keys(data.answers).forEach((key) => {
      data[
        key
          .replace(/[{()}]/g, "")
          .replace(/ :/g, "")
          .replace(/ /g, "_")
          .toLowerCase()
      ] = data.answers[key];
    });
    delete data.answers;
    return { ...data };
  });
  return { ...item, answer: mappedAns };
});
```